# Javascript array holding JSON objects convert one key value to javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have this Array with these JSON objects. I am wanting to convert a KEY value to Javascript array so it looks like . Look at the Artist key.

How can I do this?

```
json_data = [
    {
        artist: "picaso",
        cover: "http:/blah.jpg",
        genre: "illouson",
        title: "mypicture",
        uploaddate: "2019-04-22T19:48:43.454Z",
        url: "https://blah.com"
    },

    {
        artist: "malevich",
        cover: "http:/blah.jpg",
        genre: "black square",
        title: "mypicture",
        uploaddate: "2019-04-22T19:48:43.454Z",
        url: "https://blah.com/blacksquare"
    },
]
```

>

**expected output**

```
json_data = [
    {
        artist: ["picaso"],
        cover: "http:/blah.jpg",
        genre: "illouson",
        title: "mypicture",
        uploaddate: "2019-04-22T19:48:43.454Z",
        url: "https://blah.com"
    },

    {
        artist: ["malevich"],
        cover: "http:/blah.jpg",
        genre: "black square",
        title: "mypicture",
        uploaddate: "2019-04-22T19:48:43.454Z",
        url: "https://blah.com/blacksquare"
    },
]
```

Comment: Where's the Javascript? The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

Just use a simple `forEach()` loop to make the `artist` property as `Array` type:

```js
var json_data = [
{
artist: "picaso",
cover: "http:/blah.jpg",
genre: "illouson",
title: "mypicture",
uploaddate: "2019-04-22T19:48:43.454Z",
url: "https://blah.com"},

{
artist: "malevich",
cover: "http:/blah.jpg",
genre: "black square",
title: "mypicture",
uploaddate: "2019-04-22T19:48:43.454Z",
url: "https://blah.com/blacksquare"},
];
json_data.forEach((item) => item.artist? item.artist = [item.artist]: item.artist);
console.log(json_data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use map

```js
json_data = [
{
artist: "picaso",
cover: "http:/blah.jpg",
genre: "illouson",
title: "mypicture",
uploaddate: "2019-04-22T19:48:43.454Z",
url: "https://blah.com"},

{
artist: "malevich",
cover: "http:/blah.jpg",
genre: "black square",
title: "mypicture",
uploaddate: "2019-04-22T19:48:43.454Z",
url: "https://blah.com/blacksquare"},
]

console.log(json_data.map(e=>e.artist=[e.artist]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `map`:

```js
const json_data = [{
    artist: "picaso",
    cover: "http:/blah.jpg",
    genre: "illouson",
    title: "mypicture",
    uploaddate: "2019-04-22T19:48:43.454Z",
    url: "https://blah.com"
  },

  {
    artist: "malevich",
    cover: "http:/blah.jpg",
    genre: "black square",
    title: "mypicture",
    uploaddate: "2019-04-22T19:48:43.454Z",
    url: "https://blah.com/blacksquare"
  }
];

const res = json_data.map(obj => obj.artist ? { ...obj, artist: [obj.artist] } : obj);

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```